# Ambiguous Call on Microsoft WPF Authorization Example

Tags: c#, wpf, form-authentication

I'm trying to learn about Form Authorization in desktop applications, and I'm following the example that Microsoft reblogged from here: http://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/03/24/custom-authorization-in-wpf/.  An error "The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'SecretWindow.SecretWindow()' and 'SecretWindow.SecretWindow()'" generates, though, at lines 316 and 318:

```
if (parameter == null)
    view = new SecretWindow();//Error here
else
    view = new AdminWindow();//Error here
```

And errors "Type ['SecretWindow' or 'AdminWindow'] already defines a member called '.ctor' with the same parameter types on these lines 431 and 457:

```
public SecretWindow()//Error here
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

and

```
public AdminWindow()//Error here
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

To me, it looks like the ambiguous calls should just be instantiating classes SecretWindow or AdminWindow, and I can't find where the methods would already be defined in the second error.  Can anyone see what's going on?  Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

I deleted the first project and retried the tutorial, now it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What error tells you is that both class `SecretWindow` and `AdminWindow` declare their `.ctor` (constructor) with exact same signature more than once. 
Simply said, there is more than one occurence of `public SecretWindow()` and `public AdminWindow()` throughout your project.

As you can see, each generated view deriving from `Window` is a **`partial`** class, ie. it might have **some of its code in other file**, that also has definiton of either `SecretWindow` or `AdminWindow`.

For **`Windows Presentation Foundation`** every window has also pregenerated file located in `\obj\Debug` folder called `<ViewName>.g.i.cs`.
Try removing everything in `obj\Debug` folder of your project and then rebuild everything in Visual Studio.

Fastest way to go there is right click on your project name and choose **`Open Folder in File explorer`**.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer - I tried searching the project for \obj\Debug and .g.i.cs and no results were returned.  Inside each .xaml file, though is an .xaml.cs file that appears to have the same code as that .xaml's public partial class in the parent code.  Would that code be the same thing that needs to be removed from each folder?

Comment: What I meant is search for it in Windows explorer, in `<YourProjectPath>/obj/` path, not in Visual Studio itself. Those files are not visible through Visual Studio by default. Fastest way to go there is right click on your project name and choose **`Open Folder in File explorer`**.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!  I deleted everything in the \obj\Debug folder, and after the Rebuild, the errors still appear.  Any ideas on why?

Comment: Can to take a look at **AdminWindow.i.g.cs** content and let me know if there actually is a line with **public AdminWindow()**?

Comment: It doesn't appear AdminWindow.i.g.cs exists through either a Windows Explorer search or by looking through the \obj\Debug folder, Solution, etc.  Could it have been deleted after clearing the \obj\Debug folder?

Comment: Alright, it seems that's not the case. Any chance you copied over any f those views and renamed it? Perhaps old name is still there in **.xaml** file. Check it out in Visual Studio.

Comment: I don't think so, but I just deleted the project and will go through the tutorial again.  I will update with whether it works or not.  Thanks again for the help.